# Moment JS - Round up hours and limiting output to 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Can't seem to find information about how to round up the result of my hours results. Looking only limiting the output to 2 decimals.

For example, the console.log below will provide me with `1.4166666666666667` but I would like if it would round up to `1.47` (maximum of 2 decimals).

```
var startTime = $('2016-02-21 18:00');
var endTime = $('2016-02-21 19:25');
var duration = moment.duration(moment(endTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').diff(moment(startTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')));
var hours = duration.asHours()
console.log(hours);
```

Would anyone know if this is possible using moment JS? I created an example of this script here  https://jsfiddle.net/ewmq6sof/1/ if that would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to just use `.toFixed(2)`

```
var hours = duration.asHours().toFixed(2)
```

If you always want to decimals, or use `Math.round()`

```
var hours = Math.round(duration.asHours() * 100) / 100
```

if you want a maximum of two decimals.

No need for moment here.

Comment: You've done it again mmm, that's exactly what I was looking for.